# How to set number of retries in httpie?

Tags: python, httpie

How to tell [httpie](http://httpie.org) to retry for n times if the first connection failed?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that httpie has this functionality built-in, but since it is just a command-line tool, you can use some sort of retry-method in whichever shell you use httpie... For example, in `bash` something like:

```
# Retry the 5 times command if returned exit code is not 0
for i in {1..5}; do http httpie.orgs && break || echo "Retrying..."; done
```